# Use custom defined scopes with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, ransack

I have a `Product` model which belongs to a `Client` model which in turn belongs to a `Debtor` model.

I need to be able to search a `Product` by `Client` and/or `Debtor` (how do I do this with Ransack?) and based on giving a `Client` and/or `Debtor`, I need to apply some custom defined scopes based on custom conditions. For example:

- if I provide a `Client`, I would like to apply `scope1` if `condition1` is true. So `Product.search(client: @client)` would also do behind the scenes a `Product.scope1 if condition1`;
- if I provide both a `Client` and a `Debtor`, I would like to apply `scope2` if `condition2` is true. So `Product.search(client: @client, debtor: @debtor)` would also do behind the scenes a `Product.scope2 if condition2`.

Hope you understand what I would like to achieve. I looked into defining a `ransacker` on a model, but have no idea how to add scopes to the results based on some conditions. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Can't write working code for your app, because of lack of information.

But sometimes, I need to filter ransack results by some scope, optionally, when it is checked in form, for example

I use ransackers with custom scopes in such way:

In app/ransackers/custom_ransacker.rb

```
class CustomRansacker < BaseRansacker
  # value param - is passed from form, it can be string, integer, boolean, what ever.
  # you can use it, to decide which scope to apply, for example
  def eq(value)
    table[:id].in(model_ids)
  end

  def model_ids
    MyModel.my_scope.map(&:id)
  end
end
```

app/ransackers/base_ransacker.rb:

```
class BaseRansacker
  attr_reader :table

  # @param [Arel::Table] table
  def initialize(table)
    @table = table
  end

  def self.call(parent)
    new(parent.table)
  end
end
```

app/models/my_model.rb

```
class MyModel < AR::Base
  scope :my_scope, ->{ # some conditions }

  ransacker :some_field_name, callable: CustomRansacker
end
```

Comment: OK, so from what I understand, Ransack simply generates an SQL query, so in order to apply some custom scopes, I need to run the scopes, get their IDs, then use them in a custom Ransacker to build a custom SQL query. Right?

Comment: Yes, it is one of possible variants

Comment: I understand. It would've been great if I could use scopes somehow directly when defining a Ransacker...

Comment: Well, you can define your custom query in CustomRansacker class, without scope, just plain condition like "MyModel.where('some condition')"

Comment: But still I need to get the ids to be able to build a query that Ransack requires to return.